# How do I plot a graph in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have installed Matplotlib, and I have created two lists, x and y.

I want the x-axis to have values from 0 to 100 in steps of 10 and the y-axis to have values from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.1. How do I plot this graph?

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good book:

Sandro Tosi, Matplotlib for Python Developers, Packt Pub., 2009.

Answer (score 2):

Use [xlim and ylim](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#setting-limits) to set the range to be displayed, [0; 100] and [0; 1] in this case. Use [xticks and yticks](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html#setting-ticks) to control the spacing of the ticks, 10 and 0.01 in this case (11 steps for both).

#### Complete example

```
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np

# Sample data
X = np.linspace(-5, 105, 2000, endpoint = True)
Cosine, Sine = 0.45 * np.cos(0.2*X) + 0.5, 0.45 * np.sin(0.2*X) + 0.5


# Plot
pl.plot(X, Cosine)
pl.plot(X, Sine)


# Set x and y limits
pl.xlim(0.0, 100.0)
pl.ylim(0.0,   1.0)


# Set ticks for x and y axis
pl.xticks(np.linspace(0.0, 100.0, 11, endpoint = True))
pl.yticks(np.linspace(0.0,   1.0, 11, endpoint = True))


pl.show()
```

#### Result

[image: Plot created by Matplotlib]

Answer (score 0):

use the arange function to stepwise your intervals for X and Y

```
X=np.arange(0,110,10)
Y=np.arange(0,1.1,.1)
print(Y)
plt.scatter(X,Y)

Cosine = np.cos(X) + 0.5
plt.plot(X, Cosine)
plt.show()
```